# How to make cmake find installed packages

Tags: linux, debian, lxc, deb, cmake

I am trying to use cmake to compile a program and it needs to use lxc, I run the cmakelist with cmake .. and it returns -- checking for module 'lxc' -- package 'lxc' not found. However, if I run apt-get install lxc, it says that lxc is not only installed but at the newest version as well. Any ideas here? Any help is appreciated.

Using debian jessie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dev version of `lxc` package. Install `lxc-dev`

Comment: thank you, and if you know also it is returning the error for dbus-cpp, but I can't install dbus cpp however there is dbus c++, but it still returns as it can't find it. any package in dev mode that I need for that as well?

Comment: All packages for development / compiling must be (lib)[name] **-dev** : `apt install libdbus-c++-dev`

Answer (score 0):

> there is dbus c++, but it still returns as it can't find it

All packages for development / compiling must be (lib)[name]-dev :

```
apt install libdbus-c++-dev
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libdbus-c%2B%2B-dev&searchon=names